# How to set up a simple https server using a Cloudflare SSL certificate?

Tags: python, server, google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, cloudflare

I can't seem to get my server to connect over https.

I created a free Cloudflare account to get a free SSL certificate for a test server. I downloaded the origin certificate and key from Cloudflare onto my Ubuntu server running on the Google Cloud Platform.

https on port 443 is allowed in firewall options.

I tried to create a simple python https server as shown here:

```
from socketserver import TCPServer
from http.server import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
from ssl import wrap_socket

httpd = TCPServer(('localhost', 443), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.socket = wrap_socket(httpd.socket, certfile='./cert.pem', keyfile='./cert.key', server_side=True)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

It runs with no errors but does not produce any output. I try to connect from the browser by accessing https://ip_address without specifying the port since I think https connects to port 443 by default.

I ran a simple http server on port 80 and that worked.

I'm expecting to see the basic html page in the directory connected over https, but I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in the browser instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `localhost` to `0.0.0.0`.

Localhost only accepts connections from inside the machine. This is the loopback address.

`0.0.0.0` means bind to all available networks. This accepts connections from outside and inside the machine.